# iterating with auto ref or an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

Which statement is faster and optimized for loop iteration in a container :

```
for (const auto& Item : s_MyTable)
```

or

```
for (std::unordered_map<int,std::string>::const_iterator it = s_myTable.cbegin(); it != s_myTable.cend(); ++it)
```

Comment: The standard comment of this kind of question: Have you measured it?

Comment: Depends on how you use `it` in the loop. But if the loops are logical equivalent then the modern compiler will most likely create the same output.

Comment: I use items to store them in a vector.

Comment: Don't stress over these kind of micro optimizations, your compiler will generate the best possible performing code, don't worry about it and move on to real problems.

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 1):

Speaking generally, neither is "faster". They do the same thing, in the same way.

Speaking even more generally, if you really want to know, *measure it* on your system.

Speaking as generally as I possibly can, try not to care about things like this.